# games opening at double resolution with 2 monitors

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, resolution, linux-mint

Whenever I open a game on my computer, It opens at a resolution of 3840x1080 aka the resolution of both of my monitors, combined. Now some games have good resolution controls, most do not. Is there anything I can do about this?

It may be worth noting that most games are still stuck at the aforementioned resolution, even if I switch to one monitor, which makes me think it may be related to the way Nvidea writes the Xorg settings

My specs are;
Linux Mint 64 bit - nVidia 560ti

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a common issue when running games on nVidia Twinview (as the two screens are actually one 'logical' screen). Usually it's only a matter of setting the right "Metamodes" in your xorg.conf and running

> export SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=1

or add it to your ~/.bashrc

[Arch wiki - Gaming using Twinview](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Gaming_using_Twinview)

Comment: that doesn't work for me... any other suggestions?